# NameError: direction is not defined?

Tags: python, function, definition, nameerror

So I'm a first year with a little coding experience but not much and I have been given the task of making a text based adventure game. My lecturer gave us a template and to help us get started but I'm confused as to why this piece of code leads to the shell saying NameError: name 'direction' is not defined. Could anyone help a first year out?

```python
def print_menu_line(direction, leads_to):
    """This function prints a line of a menu of exits. It takes two strings: a
    direction (the name of an exit) and the name of the room into which it
    leads (leads_to), and should print a menu line in the following format:

    Go <EXIT NAME UPPERCASE> to <where it leads>.

    For example:
    >>> print_menu_line("east", "you personal tutor's office")
    Go EAST to you personal tutor's office.
    >>> print_menu_line("south", "MJ and Simon's room")
    Go SOUTH to MJ and Simon's room."""

    print(rooms[room_livingRoom["exits"]])
    direction = input("Which direction? ")
    leads_to = input("Where do you want to go? ")
    print("Go", direction, "to", leads_to)

    print_menu_line(direction, leads_to)
```

Comment: Is this an exact copy of the code you are trying to execute?

Comment: Are you trying to execute the commands without running it in a function? `direction` is defined in the function header, if you try to run it without using it as a function then you won't have defined `direction`

Comment: Clearly you are accessing "direction" before its declaration. Or the function call is happening before the "direction" is assigned any value or is given as an input. Try to check these cases by printing its value.

Comment: yeah its an exact copy

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in the code you paste. Here's the code I presume your lecturer gave to you.

```
def print_menu_line(direction, leads_to):
    """This function prints a line of a menu of exits. It takes two strings: a
       direction (the name of an exit) and the name of the room into which it
       leads (leads_to), and should print a menu line in the following format:

       Go <EXIT NAME UPPERCASE> to <where it leads>.

     For example:
     >>> print_menu_line("east", "you personal tutor's office")
      Go EAST to you personal tutor's office.
     >>> print_menu_line("south", "MJ and Simon's room")
     Go SOUTH to MJ and Simon's room."""


#print (rooms[room_livingRoom["exits"]])
direction = input("Which direction? ")
leads_to = input("Where do you want to go? ")
print("Go", direction, "to", leads_to)

print_menu_line(direction, leads_to)
```

Now, here is the solution to your problem:

```
def print_menu_line(direction, leads_to):
    """ direction and leads_to are the parameters of the function """
    direction = direction.upper() # to have a upper case 
    print("Go", direction, "to", leads_to)


# to get values <direction> and <leads_to>
# direction and lead_to are the arguments you will send to the function
direction = input("Which direction? ")
leads_to = input("Where do you want to go? ")

# call the function
print_menu_line(direction, leads_to)
```

**Update:** To understand the difference between arguments and parameters, I rewrite the code that is at the top:

```
def print_menu_line(param1, param2):
    """ param1 and param2 are the parameters of the function. From your assignment, you know that param1 refers to the direction and param2 refers to the leads_to variable """

    param1 = param1.upper() # to have a upper case 
    print("Go", param1, "to", param2)


# direction and lead_to are the arguments you will send to the function
direction = input("Which direction? ")
leads_to = input("Where do you want to go? ")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I know I'm being dumb but can I ask why the variables direction and leads_to are outside of the function?

Comment: I update the code. If the answer helps you, you should upvote and accept it!